# Откуда взялась традиция сохранять орфографию и пунктуацию при цитировании текстов?

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, цитирование

В последнее время часто вижу на телевидении пометку "Орфография и пунктуация автора сохранены", особенно в новостях, в интернет-СМИ. Такую текстовую пометку в эпоху Интернета чаще всего размещают при цитировании текстов из сети Интернет, в которых есть ошибки в написании слов, пунктуации, включая посты в соцсетях, отзывы, комментарии.

Много ошибок бывает в таких текстах: неправильно пишут слово, забывают ставить пробел между словами и т. п. По этому поводу я писал обращение в Министерство цифрового развития, связи и массовых коммуникаций Российской Федерации. В своём обращении я указывал на довольно распространённые ошибки, которые часто допускают носители русского языка, в частности, неправильное употребление окончания возвратных глаголов -ТЬСЯ/-ТСЯ, неправильное написание слов, в которых *О* произносится как *А* и т. п.

И вот такой ответ я получил из Минцифры России (орфография и пунктуация сохранены):

> Средства массовой информации в соответствии с Законом Российской Федерации от 27 декабря 1991 г. № 2124-I «О средствах массовой информации» осуществляют свою деятельность на основе профессиональной самостоятельности. Вмешательство в какой бы то ни было форме со стороны должностных лиц или государственных органов в редакционную и вещательную политику СМИ является нарушением профессиональной самостоятельности, что в соответствии с действующим законодательством недопустимо.
> Одновременно сообщаем, что изначальные орфография и пунктуация, соблюдаемые авторами комментариев в сети «Интернет», при цитировании указанных комментариев сохранены с целью избежать искажения стиля и смысла написанного, а также продемонстрировать цитируемый текст в оригинале.
> Вместе с тем обращаем Ваше внимание, что создание качественной информационной продукции требует высокого профессионализма от всех участников процесса. Важная роль отведена редакторам и редакторам-корректорам средств массовой информации, которые не только оценивают достоверность фактов, общую логику изложения, актуальность материала и прочее, но и отслеживают соблюдение норм русского литературного языка, с целью не допускать ошибок наподобие указанных в Вашем обращении.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здесь вопрос лежит скорее в юридической плоскости, а не в плоскости русского языка.
Если вы процитируете кого-то, указав, что это сказал или написал именно он, и при этом внесете какие-либо изменения в сказанное или написанное, автор цитаты получит достаточные основания для судебного иска в ваш адрес. Даже если это было просто исправление грамматических или орфографических ошибок. Ведь формально вы приписываете человеку высказывания, которые он не делал (он делал другие высказывания, *те самые, с ошибками*).
Понято, что с вашей точки зрении, Вы **улучшили** такое высказывание, но с точки зрения закона - вы его ***исказили***.
Именно поэтому многие предпочитают не подвергать себя ненужному риску и размещают цитаты с сохранением авторской орфографии и пунктуации.